# Find minimum $x+y+z$ given $3x=4y=7z$ and $x, y, z \in \mathbb N^+$

Tags: systems-of-equations, integer-programming

> Given that $x, y, z$ are positive integers and that $$3x=4y=7z$$ find
>   the minimum value of $x+y+z$. The options are:
>
> A) 33
>
> B) 40
>
> C) 49
>
> D) 61
>
> E) 84

My attempt:

$y=\frac{3}{4}x, z=\frac{3}{7}x$.

Substituting these values into $x+y+z$, I get $\frac{117}{28}x$.  I have no idea how to continue.  $x$ in this case would have to be 28, meaning that the sum is $117$, which is not one of the options

Comment: I think this question came here before: [Least Value Of $x+y+z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532139/least-value-of-xyz) The answers there might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you made a mistake.
$x+y+z=x+\frac 34x +\frac 37x=\frac {61}{28}x$.
Substituting $x=28$ gives us $\frac {61}{28}*28= 61$.
Option $D$ $(61)$ is correct.

---

You could do this in another way:
$LCM (3, 4, 7)= 3*4*7 = 84$
$\therefore 3*28=4*21=7*12$
So, Let $f(x)=x+y+z$
$f_{min}(x)= 28+21+12$
$\therefore f_{min}(x)= 61$.

Both methods are valid. Use whichever you find easier to remember.

Comment: Oh!  I was careless!  I added $3x$ instead of $x$.

Comment: NP, everyone makes mistakes. Always remember to double check (or triple check) ;)

Comment: Yes @MohammadZuhairKhan I will accept your answer in 7 minutes.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Doesn't matter much but anyway appreciated. Was this part of a class test or just practice?

Comment: Class practice.

Comment: GMAT questions for practice? Are you giving your GMATs?

Comment: Self-class practice per se.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical problem from *integer programming*. There are exact algorithmic solutions available (although they are slow, as it is known that this a NP-hard problem). You can look for "branch and bound" or "branch and cut" or *eventually*  total unimodularity. It basically works by a cleaver extension of the classicalm simplex algorithm in ordinary linear programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the smallest value that $3x$, $4y$, and $7z$ can be as the smallest multiple of three that is also a multiple of 4 and 7, or as the $gcm(3,4,7)$, which equals $84$. So if the minimum value of $3x$ is $84$, the minimum value of $x$ is $28$. Using the same method you find that $y$ equals $21$ and that $z$ equals $12$therefore the minimum value of $x+y+z$ is $28+21+12$, which equals $61$.