# Least value of $x+y+z$ where $ax=by=cz$

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

The following question is a generalization of the case $a=3$, $b=4$, $c=5$ from a MindYourDecisions YouTube video (which I am not going to actually link here).

> Given positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, what is the smallest possible value of $x+y+z$ where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers with $ax=by=cz$?

If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are pairwise coprime, then the answer is just $bc+ac+ab$, because $lcm(a,b,c)=abc$.

The case $a=3$, $b=4$, $c=7$ was asked 6 years ago in [Least Value Of $x+y+z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532139/least-value-of-xyz).

Comment: Well, $$x+y+z= \left(\frac{b}{a} + 1 + \frac{c}{b}\right)y,$$ so you should minimize $\frac{b}{a}  + \frac{c}{b}$ (assuming $a, b \neq 0$).

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang: Where you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N = ax = by = cz$. Since $N$ is a multiple of $a, b, c$ it must be a multiple of $\mathrm{lcm}(a, b, c)$. Thus, we should take
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= N/a \\
y &= N/b \\
z &= N/c
\end{align*}
$$
The sum will be minimal when $N = \mathrm{lcm}(a, b, c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

$$x_0 = bc$$
$$y_0 = ac$$
$$z_0 = ab$$

and then, if $x_0$,$y_0$ and $z_0$ share a common prime factor $p$,  divide each of them by $p$ and check again. You will end up dividing by the gcd(x_0,y_0,z_0). Thus, it's simply:

$$\min(x+y+z) = \frac{bc+ac+ab}{\gcd(bc,ac,ac)}$$

Comment: This is not correct. Take $a = 6$, $b = 15$, $c = 10$. Since $\mathrm{gcd}(a, b, c) = 1$, your solution gives the minimum is $ab + bc + ca > 150$. The method I give below finds a choice giving $x = 10$, $y=4$ and $z = 6$, giving $x+y+z = 20$.

Comment: You can't study the examples I gave if you delete your question.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324472/rules-of-analytic-continuation

Comment: haha whoops, I initially wrote it as gcd(x,y,x), but then had a brain fart and though I could replace that with gcd(a,b,c)

Comment: Also did a small mistake, and the method I propose above gives the same result of yours in the example. Interestingly enough, it seems that we are proving the following equality
$$
\mathrm{lcm}(a, b, c)(1/a + 1/b + 1/c) = (ab + bc + ca)/\mathrm{gcd}(ab, bc, ca)
$$

Comment: However, I am not entirely sure that your method works in general. You are picking some initial try and them removing extra factors, making it minimal. However, it might not be a minimum in principle. Some details are missing...